# How to catch unpickling error (Python3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I have some pickled files I want to unpickle. I know some haven't been finished properly, but I would like to get the valid information from them (every dataset has been pickled).

When I unpickle from a certain file, I get the following error:

```
     var1 = pickle.load(output_file)
    _pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

But when I try to catch the error as

```
    try:                                                                                                                          
       var2 = pickle.load(output_file)                                                                              
    except:                                                                                         
       stop_reading = True
```

program does not go into the "except" part. Interestingly it raises the error for *var1*, unpickled before *var2*, but when I debug the code it stops when unpickling *var2*.

What can I do to catch the error ?

Comment: try with the specific error `pickle.UnpicklingError`

Comment: tried with  try                                                                                                      
v1 = pickle.load(output_file)                                                                             
 except pickle.UnpicklingError:                                                                                                                        stop_reading = True but didn't work, too

Comment: try putting prints in several places to see if it really goes to the expect and/or d as expected, like `try print("before"); v1 = pickle.load(output_file); print("after") except pickle.UnpicklingError: stop_reading = True; print("error")` it might be that the error is somewhere else

Comment: it happens directly when calling `pickle.load(output_file)` and there is "some file left" to read